# How to change text unicode in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've created database with Unicode 'latin1_swedish_ci' and insert some text in it.
later I changed the Unicode in the database to 'UTF-8', then the text inside the database changed to strange text.

how i can convert the text Unicode for the text inside the database to utf-8, so I can read them again ??

Comment: I've changed database and the column but the text inside can't be read any more.
I need to rewrite the text inside the database in the new Unicode

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  here convert to utf8

ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL;